# Best Practice: Which AES settings to use for Android KeyStore

Tags: android, encryption, kotlin, aes, keystore

Android KeyStore provides a whole list of available [ciphers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#SupportedCiphers), which leads me to the following question: Which combination would be Best Practice to use in 2019? Every combination seems to have its own set of drawbacks and as someone who is not a security expert, it is realy difficult to decide which one to use.

Some background information:
I am working on a Kotlin-based Android app which connects to an API. The user must provide a pair of username:password to authenticate to the API, which will then return a hexadecimal bearer token for future authentication. The connection to the API is already TLS-encrypted, so no need for additional encryption here.
The problem is storing the informations securely. The username as well as the password and bearer token have to be stored securely. A common solution to this problem seems to be to encrypt the credentials and store them via the Preferences API. As the encryption only happens inside the app and no key-exchange is needed, symmetric-key encryption looks like the way to go.

Comment: Do you want to store your username and pass encrypted on your device? Or are you asking how you should encrypt them to send them to the Server?

Comment: I want to store username, password and bearer token encrypted on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL; DR**: Prefer `AES/GCM/NoPadding`.  Do not ever use `AES/ECB/*`.

---

In your situation, you'll want to prefer authenticated symmetric encryption, and the only option that provides this in the list you link is `AES/GCM/NoPadding`.

The benefit for you here is that, not only is your data encrypted, it is also safe from tampering - if someone or something modifies the stored data, you'll get an exception when you attempt to decrypt it.  The other listed modes do not have this property.  This means that the stored ciphertext could be modified and you wouldn't know - it may or may not still decrypt (I say may or may not as it can throw an exception in other circumstances, like bad padding after modification).

The drawback (and it isn't much of one) is that you **must** ensure you never use the same key and nonce together.  If you do - and an attacker can access or view two different sets of ciphertext - it becomes trivial for them to break and decrypt.  The easiest way around this is to simply **always generate a random nonce**.  You'll be able to encrypt `2^96` times before you run into any issues!

If you can't or don't want to use `AES/GCM/NoPadding` for whatever reason, select from `AES/CTR/NoPadding` or `AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding`.  Both have their own drawbacks.  You'll need to find a way to prevent tampering yourself (HMACs are usually used).  I tend to prefer `AES/CTR/NoPadding` as it is very similar (at least to use) to `AES/GCM/NoPadding`.

Lastly, **do not use anything ECB related**.  **ECB BAD**.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed answer!
I have 2 more questions though:

1. Is the nonce identical with the IV? How should I store the IVs?
Would it be secure to Base64-encode the IV and append it to the ciphertext (which I think to have seen in some example code)?

2. The length of the IV is limited to 96bits in AES/GCM/NoPadding. What effect does this have on the length of the key? Can I combine e.g. a 256bit AES key and a 96bit IV/Nonce?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AHahn94 A nonce and an IV are, more or less, the same yes.  A common approach is to prefix the nonce to the ciphertext and *then* base64 encode, although if you can store simply as bytes, that would be better.  The nonce and the key do not interact at all.  Their sizes **relative to each other** do not impact the operation (or security) at all.